# Jquery EasyUI datagrid scrollview bug on more than 750000 rows

Tags: php, jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I am testing a program with Jquery Easyui Datagrid.

I have table records more than 750000. Then I use scrollview to load data by chunks.
Unfortunately it is only giving first 50 records only.
Below 750000 rows working fine without any issue.

You can see the [sample code from author](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid27.php) 

[View Demo](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid27_demo.html)

Above example works because it has only 8000 rows.

You can change it as below and see what will occur.

datagrid27_getdata.php

```
$result = array();
$result['total'] = 750000;  //before 8000 only
$result['rows'] = $items;
echo json_encode($result);
```

Any help??

Thank You,
Supun

Comment: I would prefer pagination for 750000 rows data.

Comment: As you said I have enabled pagination. But it didn't work with records below 700000. It didn't change page number on bottom while I scroll it down. I think this is not the way to correct it. I think this really is a bug

Answer (score 0):

in datagrid27_demo.html file change this :
line 25:

```
    for(var i=1; i<=750000; i++){ i
```